# El Capitan froze and rebooted (Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2012)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, macos, wifi

- 2.3 Ghz Intel Core i7 8GB DDR3:
  Was running NetAdmin Pro which is monitoring 
  my office LAN, processors consumption was at 
  ~15 - 20%. Simultaneously I ran WiFI Explorer, 
  3.7% no more than 5% CPU usage. And I was 
  updating Xcode to v 7.3.1 and was browsing and 
  watching video from playground.ru
- Watch the videos until half of it (20mins) the
  Video froze I moved the mouse and turned out 
  the whole OSX is frozen.
- littleSnitch v 3.7 has no reaction
- I immediately pull the Ethernet adaptor and 
  MacBook just went to black screen. I then 
  switch off the wireless router. (My MacBook Pro 
  is connected to the network via Ethernet 
  adaptor and via WiFi router bearing different IP,
  I was thinking of cutting both network 
  communication, in case it was an intrusion)
- MacBook just restarted itself to login screen, 
  after 15-20 sec of black screen and total 
  silence)
- I again restarted and booted into Recovery 
  mode use disk utility. After completing disk 
  check.
- Login and previously opened programs resume 
  back (NetAdmin Pro, WiFi Explorer, Yandex 
  browser, Activity Monitor and AppStore)
- AppStore doesn't resume the download 
  everything else is functioning normally and in
  Addition I have got my calendar open after login
  (I did not launch accidental nor was it set to 
  start with system login)

Question 1: Are there any way to know what was happening and what was OS El Capitan last reaction before it froze and rebooted?

Question 2: Are there any software better than "Console" v10.11 to interpret what was going on before it crashes?

*P.S. Thank you in advance, I will try to upload the Console messages later from the MacBook Pro*

---

```
DDT-2:~ Chaleune$ syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"

Jun 22 14:15:37 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 22 20:34:46 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 23 15:18:23 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 24 17:58:32 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 24 20:09:52 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 24 22:58:15 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5Jun 25 14:43:36 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 25 21:55:31 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 3

Jun 25 22:20:57 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Kext com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog failed to load (0xdc008012).Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 26 10:18:44 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 26 12:09:45 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 26 18:00:31 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 27 13:05:58 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 27 22:56:11 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

Jun 28 14:18:27 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: 5

*Jun 29 18:56:21 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128*

Jun 29 23:31:22 DDT-2 kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
```

---

[Opensource.apple](http://opensource.apple.com//source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacErrors.h) shows the following

- dsIllInstErr                  = 3,    /*illegal instruction error*/
- dsChkErr                      = 5,    /*check trap error*/
- userCanceledErr               = -128

[macwizard](http://www.macwizard.com/errors.html) gave the following interpretation:

- 03 Illegal Instruction
  The computer has a specific vocabulary of machine language instructions it can understand. If a computer tries to execute an instruction that isn't in its vocabulary, you see this error code. It's less likely than error 02, but still very common.
- 05 Range Check Error
  Programmers can use an instruction in the Motorola 68000 to check if a number is within a certain range. This error indicates that the number tested isn't in the specified range.
- -128  userCanceledErr         User canceled an operation

Comment: Find out what the shutdown cause was by issuing the command `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` and post the results.  You can also run Apple [Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold down "D" while booting from a powered off state with AC adapter connected.

Comment: Jun 27 13:05:58 DDT-2 kernel Chaleune  console                   Wed Jun 29 18:56   still logged in
Chaleune  console                   Mon Jun 27 22:56 - crash (1+20:00)
Chaleune  console                   Sun Jun 26 18:00 - 22:55 (1+04:54)
Chaleune  console                   Sun Jun 26 12:09 - 12:50  (00:40)

Comment: [Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3128527?tstart=0) answers is not satisfactory. I did not have overheat, my fan works normally. Beside that I have cause 5 and 3. After replying to your message I re-run the command and now have -128. And the incident  was happening around 18:00 hrs Jun 29.

Comment: [Opensource.apple](http://opensource.apple.com//source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/MacErrors.h) shows the following - dsIllInstErr                  = 3,    /*illegal instruction error*/ - dsChkErr                      = 5,    /*check trap error*/  -   userCanceledErr               = -128

Comment: Shutdown codes are different that system errors.  However, a -128 is unidentified, but most of the time it's related to memory.  Pull out a module and run Apple Hardware Test.  Hold down D while booting from power off state with AC connected.

Comment: MBP did not restart after I chose 'Restart' command, instead it closes most of the interface leaving little snitch functional and unfunctional dock. I waited 20-25 mins then I cut the power. Booted into Recovery mode did disk firstaids then booted to AHT, chose extended test and result was PASSED.

Answer (score 2):

Run a sysdisgnose. That is how Apple receives feedback from seeding/beta customers. The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Opt</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Period</kbd>.

You can also run sudo `sysdiagnose -f ~/Desktop/` in Terminal. The former will save to `/var/tmp` and the latter will save to the Desktop.

Sysdiagnose will contain pretty much A to Z.

You should be sure to check the disks.txt, diskutil.txt, errorlog.txt, logs.txt, and the diagnostics folder.

Comment: while good advice, it's not an **answer** to the quesiton.  It's the first step in diagnosing.

Comment: @Allan correct me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty sure it answers question 2. And I think it's an implied answer to question 1 that if he reads the sys diagnose, there's a way to know what went wrong.

Comment: So, what does he look for?

Comment: @Allan answer edited. You're right. My bad.

Comment: Thank you @BoraOztekin, well I did as you have suggested, but how do I learn how to read/interpret what 'sysdiagnose' generated. It's way way too much of information for me. I was just wanted to understand the causes of today incidents and hopefully I could prevent it or at least avoid and not try to repeat the same mistakes. I have save the logs from the Console and will update it to the question.

Comment: @Kuma I'm away from my laptop but I'll check out my sysdiagnose and follow up with some pointers later...

Answer (score 2):

**[Shutdown cause numbers](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/)** are different from *Error Codes*.  For example, a [shutdown cause of 0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234846/imac-27-powering-off-without-reason/234850#234850) means that your Mac lost power.  An error code of 0 (in Bash, for example) means that the function or command  exited normally with no error.  Apple has this backward.

Using this case as an example, *Error code -128" in software means *user canceled*, while *shutdown cause -128* is undefined.

So, in the output you provided, you have 3 error codes:  3, 5, and  -128.

- cause 3 is a "dirty" shutdown meaning that something was force quit and/or the power button was held down to power off the system
- cause 5 is a clean exit and there is nothing to worry about
- cause 128 is "undefined."  However, most of the time that I have run across this has been either memory or the logic board

  - [Shutdown Cause -128](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212809/shutdown-cause-128/212810#212810)
  - [MBP Retina 15 inch, late 2013 shuts down randomly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243546/mbp-retina-15-inch-late-2013-shuts-down-randomly?noredirect=1#comment300080_243546)

The best way to diagnose this is to run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) with one of your memory modules removed (Mid-2012 and earlier.  2013 and newer models have modules that cannot be removed).  Hold <kbd>D</kbd> while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter plugged in.  If your test comes out clean, shutdown, remove the module and replace it with the first one that you removed.  Re-run AHT.

Comment: rMBP has soldered memory, so can't exactly just take one of them out.

Comment: I keep forgetting which year they went from modules to soldered RAM.  Either way, -128 is usually RAM and the 2nd link I provided was the exact same case as yours

Comment: MBP Retina Mid 2012, I did AHT with extended test, result was PASSED. Sorry I couldn't take out any memory modules as I don't have the tools. (Last time I happen to ask some dealer if they could upgrade my SSD drive, they said it soldered and can't be upgraded. So this happen with the RAM too?)

Comment: You will probably have to run AHT multiple times since this is an intermittent problem

Answer (score -1):

1. The combination of the model, video viewing(/discrete gpu usage) and the way it just respawned to the login screen makes me fairly certain it's a faulty GPU issue. Luckily there's a warranty extension repair program running until the end of the year, see http://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Check /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for .gpuRestart files to make sure.

2. Yes. `brew install lnav` and never look back.

Lastly, neither of the links you posted are about current shutdown causes, so just ignore them.

Comment: Would those who downvoted this mind explaining why? My faulty rMBP behaved exactly like this, a _very_ significant proportion of first-gen rMBP's are suffering from this issue, and I explained how he can try to confirm this issue and get a free repair from Apple if it happens to be the case.

I also answered his second question about a better syslog reader, and lnav is definitely just that.

Comment: Thank you @tolgraven for your input, I haven't voted anyone anything yet, and I had like to have more clarification before I put all the causes to GPU. regarding "lnav" : ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server

Comment: Yeah, look into it and if it turns out to be plausible then Apple will still obviously do additional extended tests before replacing the logic board.
re: brew I'm guessing you're still on your work network and it uses a proxy? Try adding --noproxy before "-fsSL" and see if it works, or just save the file using your browser and run it manually.

Comment: Thank you for answering the 2nd question, I have got it running by downloading it (no installation). Now I was wondering if it could help me reads the saved *.logs, Kernel_2016-06-25-212600_DDT-2.gpuRestart, *.diag files that @Bora Oztekin suggested? (haven't have time to read the lnav.org yet, thanks in advance)