# Mac mini (Mid 2011) randomly reboots, but not while I'm using it

Tags: kernel-panic, reboot

Very strange issue here. My Mid '11 Mac Mini (on OS X El Cap, 10.11.6) is randomly rebooting during the day and (mostly) at night when not in use. I will be up in the middle of the night getting some water and hear the Apple chime. Worth noting, I have never seen it reboot while I am using it.

I've searched for anything that says "kernel" in the Console program in OS X, but all I see are "PM kernel: Sandbox" items...are those related? Any help here much appreciated. Thank you!

[EDIT] After running the command `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"`from Terminal, I get 271 instances of the unexpected reboot over the past 5 days, all with **cause of -128**

```
Oct 28 11:02:59 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 11:37:54 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 12:07:55 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 12:35:52 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 13:56:05 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 15:52:22 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 16:03:45 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
Oct 28 16:26:52 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128
```

This repeats many, many times with entries throughout each day.  [Click here to see the full log](http://pastebin.com/isybkZJt)

Comment: Look for a message that contains `Previous shutdown cause`, for example: `Aug  8 22:00:23 localhost kernel[0]: Previous shutdown cause: 5`

Comment: You need to check for the shutdown cause - issue the command:  `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"`  Then post the output to your original question.

Comment: Thank you both. I ran the command in Terminal and it returned MANY of these (about 15 or so) for the past few days, all with cause listed as: **-128**    

`Oct 28 00:20:03 localhost kernel[0] <Notice>: Previous shutdown cause: -128`

Comment: According to this this link, the Mac is overheating or it might be 3rd party RAM (which I do have installed): https://discussions.apple.com/message/18098171#18098171

Comment: I have actually answered this very question before - see this answer:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/244285/119271

Comment: Thanks, @Allan. I ran the AHT twice and the test results were "Not trouble found." Pic here: https://goo.gl/photos/jMd7V5VTJTTHkSFD9

Comment: *No trouble found, typo.

Comment: Maybe it is just overheating? I have it sitting on top of my old Mac Pro 1.1, but I usually have the MP off. I'm trying setting the Mac Mini on its side to see if that helps.

Comment: BUMP. Can anyone help here??

Comment: Still stuck here. Probably has actually worsened and the Mac Mini boot loops at the Apple Logo now. However AHT says no problems found and I can boot to Safe Mode fine.

Comment: Thank you, @Allan. Wipe/reload of the OS fixed the issue, but your feedback definitely helped me.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a software issue. A **clean install of the OS** fixed the issue. I could not get the recovery partition to boot, so I had to use another Mac to [create a bootable USB installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372) (downloaded from the App Store).

Worth noting, I was able to put all my apps and settings back into place via Migration Assistant, BUT only *after* booting into macOS (not on first boot during setup where it prompts for Migration Assistant - it failed there for some reason).

Comment: NOPE, I was wrong! It was **sleep that was causing the reboots!!** I have not just set the Mac Mini *and* the monitors to NEVER sleep (I turn the monitors off and/or use a screensaver) and the boot loops have stopped. Worth noting that a clean install of OS X did *seem* to get the initial boot loops to stop (when powering on the Mac Mini), but I think a SMC reset and/or PRAM reset might do the same, not sure.