# rBMP 11,3 - shutdown code -128

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My 11,3 rMBP has been freezing of late (with shutdown cause of -128) but this is only in OSX, Bootcamp & Safe mode runs also fail.Diagnostics report a healthy system. Cleared the PRRAM/SMC (multiple times) & did full format/re-installs of osx. issue still occured

Is this likely hardware related??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [El Capitan froze and rebooted (Macbook Pro Retina Mid 2012)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244241/el-capitan-froze-and-rebooted-macbook-pro-retina-mid-2012)

Comment: @Allan thanks - I'm aware of this answer but it doesn't explain to why that if it was a logicboard/RAM issue then the issue isn't apparent in bootcamp/safe mode

Comment: Because with issues like this (assuming memory for the time being), it will only present if/when the faulty area is accessed.  If it's not accessed in Bootcamp for whatever reason, it won't present.  For example, I had a MBP that would crash and kernel panic due to a faulty GPU on boot but would boot FreeBSD no problem.